# DirectX11 CreateShaderResourceView FromMemory or FromResource

Tags: c++, winapi, directx-11

*Excuse me for my low english skills, I hope you will edit my post if you got enough karma.*

I am trying to initialize ShaderResourceView from the Win32 Program Resource. I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Next code fails:

```
HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandleW(0);
HRSRC hRes = FindResourceW(hMod, (const wchar*)MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), RT_BITMAP);
HGLOBAL hGlob = LoadResource(hMod, hRes);
DWORD dwImageSize = SizeofResource(hMod, hRes);
byte *lpResourceData = (byte*)LockResource(hGlob);

HRESULT hr = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromMemory(lpDevice, lpResourceData, dwImageSize, NULL, NULL, &lpNodeTexture, NULL);

if(FAILED(hr)) {
    Int3();
}

FreeResource(hGlob);
```

All of these WinApi functions are succeeded and I really have this resource in my program, but hresult always returns E_FAIL. Can you pls give me an advice. Thank you.

**EDITED:**

I forgot to add next code as well to the first post:

```
D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFileW(lpDevice, L"Node.bmp", 0, 0, &texture, 0).
```

Its working for me, but I need to pack my textures into application. Can the problem be more difficult than creating D3D Device with Debug Layer flag? Thanks.

Comment: In DX11 `E_FAIL` has a specific meaning: *Attempted to create a device with the debug layer enabled and the layer is not installed.* Presumably `lpDevice` relates to a device created with the debug layer active when the layer itself is not subsequently available, iirc the DX SDK need to be installed for that to be the case.

Comment: For details on the real story of the debug device, see [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/).  Also keep in mind ``D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromMemory`` is a D3DX11 function which is itself deprecated. See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/)

Comment: You don't have any error detection on all those functions, so I'd recommend that to see which function is actually failing.

Comment: @AlexK, thank you guys for advices. I checked out my code, I really thought I creating my Device with Debug Layer flag, but its not like that. Next code explains my comment: `hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(0, d3dDriverType, 0, 0, featureLevels, feautreLevelNum, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &lpSwapChain, &lpDevice, &d3dFeatureLevel, &lpDC);` And I forgot to add next code aswell to the first post: `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFileW(lpDevice, L"Node.bmp", 0, 0, &texture, 0)`. Its working for me, but I need to pack my textures into application. Can the problem be more difficult? Thanks.